# How to prevent spotted border in navbar for selected tab

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, border, navbar

I started using bootstrap now and really like it but a problem came up now.

I made an adapted navbar and when a tab is selected, there is a spotted border that I dont like. How can I prevent this border (CSS)?

Comment: Example HTML + CSS are always a helpful part of posting a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you add some code?
I think somewhere in your CSS you will find something like: `border: 1px dotted #ccc;` Change that to: `border: none;`

Comment: thanks. "a:focus{outline:thin dotted #333..." was the 'problem'. changed it to "outline:none" and it works

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what class/id you have it will be something along the lines of:

```
border:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a limb and assume the HTML for your tab is an . If so, make sure you are explicitly defining the border you want in all of its states (CSS psuedo-classes), specifically :active

```
a:link {border-width:0;}     /* unvisited link */
a:visited {border-width:0;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {border-width:0;}    /* mouse over link */
a:active {border-width:0;}   /* selected link */
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp